# Placing placeholder in TINY MCE at current caret position

Tags: tinymce

i want to place a palceholder in the tiny MCE at the current caret position.
tried bookmarking also but not helping :(
Need help

thanks in advcance,
naman

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of bookmarks in tinymce.

You could use for example: `var b = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark(2,true);`
and later on: `tinymce.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(b);`